# unclear semantics of some fio options

Tags: linux, sync, io

I am doing some raw disk tests using `fio`. I found some behaviour are not clear when I specify `--filename=/dev/device_name` and `--direct=1`. Could please help me to explain it?

- (1) default `ioengine` is `sync`, which use read(2)/write(2), but for raw disks, there is no filesystem. So I am wondering how `fio` read/write raw disks? The same question for `libaio`, `posix_aio` engine.
- (2) what will fio do for the raw device when I specify `sync=sync`. I know fio use `O_SYNC` when testing files. But what for raw disks. The same question for `fsync=1` option.
  Further, if I use `libaio` or `posix_aio` engine, what will fio do if I specify `sync=sync` and `fsync=1` options. (Only using `--direct=1` is not enough for me, since I want to make sure the write is right on the storage mediem (e.g., TLC NAND for SSD) rather than disk cache.)
- (3) the result report has an "in_queue" time which is documented as "Total time spent in the disk queue". I want to know the unit of this data (ns/us/ms).

Thank you very much for the patience!

Comment: (Doing a Google search this seems very similar to  https://github.com/axboe/fio/issues/1179#issue-802658223 ... Assuming you've seen the answer there, can you identify the parts that are wrong/missing that could be added here?)

Comment: this issue is posted by me. I think I can reference it here. Thanks.